# How to extract some information such as the meta and the topic using url or the page and JQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider I have a URL, now I want to have some information associated with the URL on my page same way as Facebook or other websites such as LinkedIn do. You submit a URL and the data about the website is retrieved to be submitted. I am using JQuery and HTML for an application and want to know how to do this thing. My application has few URL's retrieved from the different sources. I want to show some of the information instead of plane URL's. How is it possible to make such a thing using JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access external URL's directly by AJAX calls because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). What you'll have to do is to submit a request to your own server, and have some serverside code request the external URL and retreive information.

How that is best achieved depends on what serverside setup you're running.

- [.NET example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513000146/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070601-1.shtml)
- [PHP example](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/web-scrape-with-php-tutorial)

(basically just google "Screen scraping" + your language of choice)

Comment: I was expecting that answer ... Thanks.. ll get along with the way you told.

Comment: I recommend third party components such as [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you want to do advanced stuff such as finding all images in the document, as Facebook does. For easier information, say, just pulling the document title, the agility pack may be a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the whole page to search for images or useful information.

Comment: I alerady got an answer which I was expecting. It wont work without the help of Server side language due to Same Origin Policy.